# Adding Chartboost in cocos2dx

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, chartboost

I am adding chartboost in cocos2dx project i have downloaded a chartboost wrapper for cocos2dx and when i am adding libraries like QuartzCore, SystemConfiguration, and CoreGraphics frameworks, and weak-link (set as Optional) the AdSupport and StoreKit.

I am getting this error.

> ld: library not found for -lcurl clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I havnt done anything just adding libraries and getting this error.

EDIT :

This wrapper i am using 
https://github.com/wenbin1989/Chartboost-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not Chartboost problem. Add library search path for libCurl.

Drag this folder to your library search path in Xcode.

```
 cocos2dx/platform/third_party/ios/libraries
```

Answer (score 1):

which Xcode Vesrion you are using ?

you don't need to add QuartzCore and CoreGraphics , they are by default added.The problem you are getting might not be by adding these frameworks , but by adding Chartboost files in the project.Any ways do one thing

Before adding the frameworks and chartboost files. Note down the contents of Header search path and Link Library search path in a notepad and after adding them again check these paths and see if the **already existing paths** are changed. Most probably now you will be seeing these paths with in **\" \"**,  back slash is escape character here. so either replace these modified paths with the actual one you noted or just remove \" from path. It should work

EDIT: Please let me know which wrapper you are using